# What is the biggest number of astronauts in EVA at the same time ever reached in space history?

Tags: iss, record, eva

At present days, it's common to have two astronauts/cosmonauts in EVA at the same time during ISS maintenance (or experiments or when expanding the station). But there was a time when three or more people were in EVA at the same time?

If yes, what is the biggest number ever reached and when it happened?

Comment: Considering that we have two permanently crewed space stations now, as well as the first private, commercial EVA on Polaris Dawn, currently scheduled for end of 2022, we might get to a point where we have more than three people on EVA, but not on the same one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current record was set during [STS 49](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-49) on May 13th 1992: **three people** at a time.

*[A NASA website states that a three man EVA was done only once](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/spacesuits/facts/). Virtually all EVA's today are performed in pairs.*